# How can i detect the tabbar item changes from Edit in 'More' tabbar item?

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, edit, uitabbaritem

I have 6 tab bar items, 4 titles shown directly and other 2 are in 'More'. I have added 'cell background image' on More tableview. Now the problem is, When i click "Edit" button in More tabbar item and change the tab bar items the tableview 'background image' not displaying after the changes. How can i detect the edit button pressed and the tabbar item changes? Please help me to find the solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer for my question and completed the issues. Apple Document describes lot about this. [Use this link](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)
 My special thanks to mattjgalloway. Thanks.